# QGIS 2.18 : Choosing path of file for Python init function

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-2.18, qt-designer

I'm using a custom feature form for QGIS 2.18 (custom `.ui` file + custom `Form.py` file containing the Python `init` function used by the form). I would like to be able to put the `.ui` file and the `Form.py` file anywhere I want because the final form will be used by several people and thus should be located in a shared folder, not a user-specific folder. I have been able to do that easily for the `.ui`, but QGIS is unable to find the `Form.py` unless I put it in QGIS 2.18 `bin` folder.

How can I tell QGIS to look for the `Form.py` in another folder than `bin`? Here's an abstract from the corresponding XML file:

```xml
<editform>C://My_path/mycustom.ui</editform> *<!--This works fine-->*
<editforminit>mycustomForm.mycustomfunction</editforminit>  
<editforminitcodesource>1</editforminitcodesource>  
<editforminitfilepath>C://My_path/mycustomForm.py</editforminitfilepath> *<!--This does not seem to work: QGIS keeps ignoring the path I provide here-->*
<editforminitcode></editforminitcode>  
<featformsuppress>0</featformsuppress>  
<annotationform>.</annotationform>  
<editorlayout>uifilelayout</editorlayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution - don't know if it's the best one, but it's fine by me.
I added a [startup.py](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#run-python-code-when-qgis-starts) file in the *.qgis2/python* folder. This file must contain the following lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Path/to/my/folder')
```

I think you can add as many folders as you want - just add more "sys.path.append" lines in your file if you want to add more than one folder.